# Django polls app not taking votes on selecting and clicking votes

Tags: python, django, django-views

Problem statement : 
I am new to Django and trying polls app. am currently in the place where we create vote function to accept votes and show results. but problem am facing is it's not capturing the vote. when I go to the results page it shows the names but no votes.Below are the code and snips.

```
 def results(request, question_id):
    i = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, "span/results.html", {'i': i})


def vote(request, question_id):
    i = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = i.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except:
        return render(request, 'span/detail.html', {'i': i, 'error_message': "Please select a choice "})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('span:results', args=(i.id,)))
```

above is my views.py

and below shoing my detail:

```
{% extends 'span/base.html' %}

{%block main_content %}
<h1> {{i.question_text}}</h1>
{% if error_message %} <p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action = "{%  url 'span:vote' i.id %}" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for j in i.choice_set.all %}
        <input type = "radio" name = "j" id="j{{forloop.counter}}" value = "{{j.id}}"/>
        <label for ="j{{forloop.counter}}">{{j.choice_text}}</label> <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type = "submit" value = "vote">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

and my result

```
{% extends 'span/base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}

<h1> {{i.question_text}}</h1>

<ul>
    {% for j in i.choice_set.all %}
        <li>
            {{j.choice_text}} -- {{j.votes}} vote{{ j.votes|pluralize}}

        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href =  "{% url 'span:detail' i.id %}"> vote again? </a>
{% endblock %}
```

Also adding snips:

[Going to the 1st page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLAnP.png)

[On selecting an Option and clicking on vote it directs me to the same page with an error message so basically, it's not recognising the input that's what I think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emKo6.png)

[This is the result page it's not capturing the votes but ist displaying other thing and also the vote again option is working too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFAiI.png)

Thank You, please let me know any further info.

Comment: Did you try putting the edition part inside the `try` block?

Comment: as in, not getting your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    i = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST["choice"]:
            selected_choice = i.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('span:results', args=(i.id,)))
        else:
            return render(request, 'span/detail.html', {'i': i, 'error_message': "Please select a choice "})
    return render(request, 'span/detail.html', {'i': i})
```

**Explanation**

First you have to know what method is being used, in this case we need the `POST` that is why I added the conditional, then we check if the `choice` parameter come in the `POST` if not we return the error, your `try, except, else` won't work because you are using a `nude except` so the else condition won't never be executed.

Let me know if it helped you

Comment: am getting this error - UnboundLocalError at /span/2/vote/
local variable 'i' referenced before assignment